# How to declare double const* const* variable in cython?

Tags: constants, cython

I have a c++ function in "example.h":

```
bool myFunc(double const* const* p);
```

and I want to wrap it with cython code (in .pyx file).
Howerver, when I'm write the following code:

```
cdef extern from r"example.h":
    bool myFunc(double const*const* p)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Error compiling Cython file:
>   Expected ')', found '*'

and pycharm shows this error on double const* const* p:

> Unresolved reference 'const'

How can I declare that kind of variables?

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, there is ongoing battle where to put the `const`-qualifier: either

```
void foo(const int *a);
```

or

```
void foo(int const *a);
```

both meaning the same thing.

There is no such battle in Cython, because it accept only the first version.

The above rule, applied to `double**` leads to:

```
cdef extern from r"example.h":
    bool myFunc(const double * const* p)
```

Or as a work-around one could drop the const-qualifier altogether:

```
cdef extern from r"example.h":
    bool myFunc(const double **p)
```

which I would **not** recommend, all above in large projects, where using const-qualifiers helps a lot when figuring out what happens.

Comment: still doesn't work... now the error is "Unresolved reference 'p' "